# Neo4J contains all Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm brand new to neo4j and graph databases.

I'm trying to create a query I would describe as a 'contains all' however I think I'm very far away and not sure how to progress

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actors)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)
RETURN movie2.name
```

Let's say 
`MATCH (movie:Movie{name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actors)` 
returns 5 actors

I'm looking to match exactly (all 5 actors -> same 5 actors as guest stars) or as a subset (all 5 actors are a subset of a movie which has 10 guest stars).

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Take a look at the Collection Predicate functions in Cypher: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-predicates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would point out is that you should call the variable `actor` instead of `actors`.  It may seem picky, but it's a common confusion with Cypher.  With the `MATCH` you are matching one sub-pattern at a time.

So to start out let's find each `movie2` and get an array of the actors in question:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actor)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)
RETURN movie2.name, collect(actor)
```

A first instinct might be to extend the path like so:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actor)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)-[:guest_starts_in]-(actor2)
```

But again, we're matching every possible match of that path in the database.  So for each `actor`, we're going to match all possible `actor2`s, which would lead to duplicates.

What we can do, though, is to take our first query and change the `RETURN` to a `WITH` in order to pass our data onto a second part of the query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actor)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)
WITH movie2, collect(actor) AS original_movie_actors
MATCH movie2-[:guest_stars_in]-(guest_star)
RETURN movie2.name, original_movie_actors, collect(guest_star) AS guest_stars
```

This gives us

- a list of movies in question
- the list of the actors who both stared in "tropic thunder" and guest stared in the movie in question
- all guest stars for the movie in question

From here you could probably figure it out in your programming language of choice.  But we can figure this out in Cypher too:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actor)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)
WITH movie2, collect(actor) AS original_movie_actors
MATCH movie2-[:guest_stars_in]-(guest_star)
WITH movie2, original_movie_actors, collect(guest_star) AS guest_stars

RETURN
  movie.name,
  ALL(guest_star IN guest_stars WHERE guest_star IN original_movie_actors) AS all_matched,
  length(original_movie_actors) / length(guest_stars) AS percentage_match
```

I threw in a `percentage_match` as a double-check and in case that's useful

Comment: What a wonderful answer. Thanks Brian - that's helped my understanding of cypher and graph databases a lot. Clearly I was expecting too much from the graph db. This solution (whilst clearly a different syntax) has made me realise that I still need to think in SQL-ly way in terms of Joins. Thanks again!

Comment: Just an add on - the solution I found that worked is:

`MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'tropic thunder'})-[:stars_in]-(actor)
      -[:guest_stars_in]-(movie2)
WITH movie, movie2, collect(actor) AS original_movie_actors
MATCH movie2-[:guest_stars_in]-(guest_star)
WITH movie, movie2, original_movie_actors, collect(guest_star) AS guest_stars
RETURN
  movie.name,
  ALL(guest_star IN guest_stars WHERE guest_star IN original_movie_actors) AS all_matched,
  length(original_movie_actors) / length(guest_stars) AS percentage_match`

Comment: I needed to add 'movie' to the WITH statements otherwise it was marked as undeclared by the RETURN

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely still an element of thinking about joins.  It's funny because so many things in the world of computers expect tables, so Cypher is build to help you turn sub-graph patterns into tables, which comes with some denormalization